# XSLT Creating Links using XSL and XML

Tags: html, xml, xslt, hyperlink, href

I’m trying to create an html e-book transforming an xsl and an xml file.
I want to create Links that let you jump from the index to the different chapters. I have to create the links in the XSL File.

The XML looks like this:

```
<book>
<chapter>
    <title>  Chapter 1</title>
    <para> aaaaa </para>
</chapter>
<chapter>
    <title>  Chapter 2 </title>
    <para> bbbb </para>
</chapter>
<chapter>
    <title>  Chapter 3 </title>
    <para> ccccccc </para>
</chapter>
</book>
```

I already tried a few methods. I started with:

```
    <xsl:element name="a">
        <xsl:attribute name="href">
            <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
    </xsl:element>
```

But when I klick on a link in the html it gives me this error:
*Firefox can’t find the file at /C:/Users/tzsch/Desktop/EPubIII/Outputs/*

So I tried using HTML id and href attributes in the xsl like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="info/title"/>
    <a id="title"/>
```

and:

```
  <xsl:element name="a">
        <xsl:attribute name="href">
            <a href="#title" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
  </xsl:element>
```

But that  only reloads the page but doing nothing when I use the link.
I'm unfortunatly not really experienced with XSL so I dont have any idea left what I can do.

I hope I described my problem detailed enough. Thanks everyone for reading this.
I hope you can help me here. Feel free to ask more questions :)

Comment: Do you have the proper HTML for your chapters and for your index? Do you know how to use a link with HTML? If you know that then with XSLT all you need to make sure you create different ids for the different chapters and link to these ids. But you need to have an understanding of HTML first before you can use XSLT to generate HTML. Please show us the HTML you want or create for a certain `chapter`.

Comment: The HTML should look like this:  
`#Link to the chapter  
<i><a href="#title">D&auml;umelieschen.</a></i>   
#Beginning of the chapter  
</section><section><article><h1>D&auml;umelieschen.<a id="titel"></a></h1>`  
  
But when i try the Method i described i get it like this:  
  
`#Link to the chapter  
<i><a href="">D&auml;umelieschen.</a></i>  

#Beginning of the chapter  
</section><section><article><h1>D&auml;umelieschen.<a id="titel"></a></h1>`  
So setting the id works but setting the href not.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the code snippets there in a readable and formatted manner, no need to stuff them in a comment. If you want to link to an element with `id="titel"` then your anchor needs to use the same id e.g. `href="#titel"` and not a different name or spelling like `href="#title"`. It is still not clear whether you are struggling with the HTML you need to have a link or with the XSLT to generate a link in HTML.